# Using Ampscript to Look Up Rows with an OR condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a DE 'ent.Automations'. I want to look up rows where field 'IsActive' = 1 **OR** field 'LastRunStatus' = 'Error'.

My current code below uses the LookUpOrderedRows function but this only applies an AND operation to additonal column and values pairs (in this case the additonal column and value pair is 'LastRunStatus' = 'Error'. How can I achieve my desired rowset, i.e. using the OR operation?

```
SET @rowset = LookUpOrderedRows('ent.Automations', 500, 'MID ASC, AutomationName ASC', 'IsActive', 1, 'Status', 'Paused Schedule', 'LastRunStatus', 'Error')
```

Comment: there is not an OR operator with ampscript lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that method for a data extension does not seem possible:
either find another method for you needs
OR you could calculate it in another field.
and using your Column and Value  to get those rows

E.G.

new field **ActiveOrError** with values "**1**", "**0**"

SET @rowset = LookUpOrderedRows('ent.Automations', 500, 'MID ASC, AutomationName ASC', '**ActiveOrError**', **1**, 'Status', 'Paused Schedule', 'LastRunStatus', 'Error')

Comment: Thank you, based on your suggestion I created a new field with an IF statement and was able to use this to filter the rows accordingly.

Comment: once you get the right answer mark it as answered, not to say mine is the correct answer, but it might help others in the future.

Comment: No worries, thanks, marked as answered